# My Python program won't terminate properly?

Tags: python, windows

When I use the command to terminate the program, it does not terminate and instead assumes that I want to open another program when I say 'no'
Here's my code:

```
import getpass
print 'Hello', getpass.getuser(), ', welcome!'
do = raw_input ('What program would you like to open? ')
if do.lower() == 'browser' or 'internet' or 'Chrome' or 'Google chrome':
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open ('www.google.com')
    oth = raw_input ('Are there any others? ')
    if oth.lower() == 'yes' or 'ye' or 'yeah':
        oth2 = raw_input ('Please name the program you would like to open! ')
else:
    import sys
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at:

```
if do.lower() == 'browser' or 'internet' or 'Chrome' or 'Google chrome':
```

Here you have several statements that always evaluate to True; each of 'internet' or 'Chrome' or 'Google chrome' is a a non-empty string. It doesn't matter what values `do.lower()` has. This means python sees that line as the equivalent of if something or True.

What you want to do instead is use the `in` operator to test if `do` is one of several options:

```
if do.lower() in ('browser', 'internet', 'chrome', 'google chrome'):
```

Note that I lowercased *all* options in the list to test; after all, you lowercase your input as well, so it'll never match "Chrome"; it'll be "chrome" or something else.

The same applies to your `if oth.lower() == 'yes' or 'ye' or 'yeah':` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
if oth.lower() == 'yes' or 'ye' or 'yeah':
```

You problem is in the above line.

In python, the truth value of a string depends on whether it is empty or not.  e.g. `bool('')` is `False`.  `bool('ye')` is `True`.

You probably want something like:

```
if oth.lower() in ('yes','ye','yeah'):
```

Consequently, you have the same problem in your browser check.